# I am stucked in some of this question about sample space and probability

Tags: probability

1. What is the size of the sample space for the following scenario:

> Roll $3$ six-sided dice, and discard the highest roll

In this question I know that sample space is all possible outcomes so the set should be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, right? So the answer should be $5^3$? I am really confused about this so please help me

2. What is the probability that you will be dealt a 5-card hand that contains no Face Cards?

In this question I know that there is 2,598,960 possible hand but I am stuck in how to find a probability for this question

Thanks for reading and helping me

Comment: 1. Can you rephrase the question? It is unclear.  Do you discard the highest die of the 3? 2. Hint: How many cards are there to choose from if you eliminate face cards? do you know combination notation?

Comment: i know the combination notation yes,

Comment: there are will be 52 - 12 card which is 40 card

Comment: How many ways to choose 5 out of 40? And how many total hands? Make sure you know how to get the number 2,598,960.

Comment: 658008 is the total hand so i just need to use 658008/2,598,960 right ?

Comment: That seems correct to me.

Comment: thanks man so how about that first question. I dont know how to rephrase it. it is all I see from the book

Comment: I don't think it's $5^3$ since you could get $(6,6,6)$ for example and would discard a 6.

Comment: oh so the answer could be 36 right ?

Comment: in my book there is 4 answer that I can choose from. which is 12, 18 , 36 , 216

Comment: Part 1 is a bit silly because there are multiple ways to define such a sample space. (In general, the elements of a sample space don't all have to have the same probability!)

Comment: i see man I am stucked in that question too. That's all it said on the book

Comment: 36 is probably correct, but the question wording just seems a little unclear to me.

Comment: yeah i see thanks for answering it

Comment: I think $36$ may be the _book's_ answer, provided that we're supposed to treat $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ as the same as each other but different from $(2,1,3)$; but given a problem that asked for actual probabilities, I would likely construct a sample space consisting of the original $216$ rolls, and drop the highest die only when trying to find all rolls that belong to the particular event(s) in question (such as "both remaining dice are $3$ or less").

Comment: After rethinking it, @David K's thought about events shows it should be 216. Then we can even ask questions like "what is there probability that the 1st die was discarded and the remaining two are both even and the third is greatest". In this way the sample space is always going to be the "largest possible one" (within reason maybe).

Answer (score 4):

Students are often asked to identify **the** sample space. However, in many cases there is more than one natural candidate for sample space. It can be convenient, when possible, to use a sample space in which all outcomes are equally likely. In our problem, it is convenient to imagine the dice to blue, white, and red, and to use as sample space all ordered triples $(b,w,r)$, where $b$ is the number showing on the blue, $w$ the number showing on the white, and $r$ is the number showing on the red. This sample space has $216$ elements.

For the second question, there are $\binom{52}{5}$ ways to choose a $5$-card hand. With proper shuffling, these are close to equally likely.

We now count the "favourables." There are $12$ face cards, and therefore $40$ non-face cards. There are therefore $\binom{40}{5}$ to choose a hand all of whose cards are non-face.

The required probability is therefore $\frac{\binom{40}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.

Now let us do this another way, that illustrates the fact that there is not necessarily only one suitable sample space.

Imagine picking the cards one at a time, and record what we got, in order. There are $(52)(51)(50)(49)(48)$ possibilities, all equally likely.

How many of these sequences are favourable? It is $(40)(39)(38)(37)(36)$. For the probability, divide.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question 1 (that's all I have time for, sorry) is as follows.  First, without "dropping the highest roll", the outcomes are triples
$$
(x_1, x_2, x_3)
$$
of scores from the three dice.  If, say, you roll the three dice, and die 1 yields score $x_1 = 3$, die 2 yields score $x_2 = 5$, and die 3 yields score $x_3 = 2$, then the outcome is $(3, 5, 2)$.  Dropping the highest of these scores would leave the pair $(3, 2)$.

So, your outcomes are pairs of scores, which came from triples of scores with a maximum dropped.

These pairs, however, are not equiprobable.

Comment: By "pairs of scores" do you mean **unordered** pairs? Your notation $(3,2)$ seems to imply that the outcomes are **ordered pairs**. In that case, what ordered pair outcome do you get if you roll $(3,2,3)$?

Comment: Ordered pairs, in the order of the way your dice are labeled: die 1, die 2, die 3 -> (score from die 1, score from die 2, score from die 3).

Comment: OK, so if the  3-dice outcome is $(3,2,3),$ is your ordered pair outcome $(3,2)$ or $(2,3)$? **How do you handle ties?**

Comment: Good question, and the answer is not clear to me either.  (I think some other participants have also voiced concern with the ambiguity of the question.)

Answer (score 0):

The sample space in 1 is just $6^3=216$.

You can find the probability of any outcome by finding the number of instances of the outcome, then dividing by 216. You can find the number of instances in problem 1 by solving a simpler problem, then solving a slightly more complicated problem, then continuing until you find a general pattern or just get to your answer.

In the simplest case, we consider a one-sided die. We roll $\{(1,1,1)\}$, and remove one of the ones, which leaves us with the entire sample space. Now we move onto a two-sided die (or a coin). We can roll: $\{(1,1,1);(1,1,2);(1,2,1);(2,1,1);(1,2,2);(2,1,2);(2,2,1);(2,2,2)\}$. After removing the highest number, we get $\{(1,1);(1,1)(1,1);(1,1);(1,2);(1,2);(1,2);(2,2)\}$. Note that $(1,1)$ appears once with $1$ as the highest number and three times with $2$ as the highest number in the sample size, $(1,2)$ appears three times with $2$ as the highest number, and $(2,2)$ once with $2$ as the highest number. Now we will consider a three-sided die. We can roll: 
$$\{(1,1,1);(1,1,2);(1,2,1);(2,1,1);(1,1,3);(1,3,1);(3,1,1);(1,2,2);(2,1,2);(2,2,1);(1,2,3);(1,3,2);(2,1,3);(2,3,1);(3,1,2);(3,2,1);(1,3,3);(3,1,3);(3,3,1);(2,2,2);(2,2,3);(2,3,2);(3,2,2);(2,3,3);(3,2,3);(3,3,2);(3,3,3)\}$$

Quick note: These are arranged by what group the dice will leave when the largest die is removed.

Removing the highest die, we are left with:
$$\{(1,1);(1,1);(1,1);(1,1);(1,1);(1,1);(1,1);(1,2);(2,1);(2,1);(1,2);(1,2);(2,1);(2,1);(1,2);(2,1);(1,3);(1,3);(3,1);(2,2);(2,2);(2,2);(2,2);(2,3);(2,3);(3,2);(3,3)\}$$

This leaves us with $7$ instances of $(1,1)$, $9$ instances of $(1,2)$, $3$ instances of $(1,3)$, $4$ instances of $(2,2)$, $3$ instances of $(2,3)$, and $1$ instance of $(3,3)$.

From this we can determine that the number of instances of $(m,m)$ with a maximum die roll of $n$ to be $3*(n-m)+1$. The "$+1$" part comes from the instance $(m,m,m)$. The "$3*(n-m)$" part comes from the case $(m,m,o)$, where $m<o\leq n$ (because $o$ has to be removed), because there are three combinations $\{(m,m,o);(m,o,m);(o,m,m)\}$ with two $m$s and one $o$ for every o that satisfies $m<o\leq n$. There are $(n-m)$ such $o$s. We can determine that the number of instances of $(m,o)$ where $m < o$ with a maximum die roll of $n$ to be $6*(n-o)+3$. The "$+3$" part comes from the cases $\{(m,o,o);(o,m,o);(o,o,m)\}$. The other part, "$6*(n-o)$", comes from the case $(m,o,p)$, where $m<o<p\leq n$, because there are there are six combinations $\{(m,o,p);(m,p,o);(o,m,p);(o,p,m);(p,m,o);(p,o,m)\}$ with one $m$, one $o$, and one $p$ for all $p$ that satisfy $m<o<p\leq n$. There are $(n-o)$ such $p$.

In summary, use the formula $3*(n-m)+1$ to determine the number of instances of $(m,m)$, where $n$ is the maximum possible number on the die. Use the formula $6*(n-o)+3$ to determine the number of instances of $(m,o)$, where $m<o$. It is important to note that $(m,o)$ and $(o,m)$ are equivalent.

For problem 2, you are trying to find out how many ways to pick five cards out of forty and order doesn't matter. This is just a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). The formula is $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, where $n$ is the total amount of possible choices, and $r$ is the number you have to choose.